# How to resize/maximize Firefox window during launching Selenium Remote Control?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-rc, automated-tests

I am using [Selenium Remote Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29#Selenium_Remote_Control) . During executing the tests the actual Firefox window is so small. I want it full screen so I can see what is happening. How can I maximize the browser screen?

Comment: What programming language are you using with Selenium-RC? java, C# or what?

Comment: How to resize/maximize FF by executing Selenium WebDriver?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try the windowMaximize command:

```
selenium.windowMaximize();
```

You can also set a specific width and height using the following command:

```
selenium.getEval("window.resizeTo(X, Y); window.moveTo(0,0);")
```

Where X is the width and Y is the height.

Comment: And for those of you using Python, the call is, predicably, `my_selenium_instance.window_maximize()`

Comment: The eval does not work on newer versions of Firefox.  See Eli Colner's answer.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes, in python it is actually `maximize_window()`

Answer (score 27):

This works for me.  All the other solutions didn't work in FF7.

```
WebDriver driver = ((WebDriverBackedSelenium) selenium).getWrappedDriver();
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

Comment: seems to be the only way on FF7+ (for me it is FF9.0.1 on OSX)

Comment: Works with only the 2nd two lines of the answer since I run with pure Webdriver without Selenium.   Thanks.

Comment: Javascript version: ``driver.manage().window().setSize(1920, 1080);``

Comment: user85461, what do you mean by Javascript version? As in the equivalent call using WebDriverJS binding? Don't want other users to be confused thinking you can execute that as plain javascript and it will simply work.

Comment: Just wanted to point out so other users don't get mistaken. This code is for Java (or also possibly C#). The syntax for other WebDriver language bindings will be different and those other ones won't have line 1 with the WebDriverBackedSelenium.

Comment: well im still confused, where does this code go then?

Comment: i use selenium ide, and run a java batch from my testing server (linux) directly on my windows machine where the selenium processes.  does this go on the java batch, or somewhere in the selenium ide?

Comment: here is my batch file `@ECHO OFF
SET JRE_HOME=C:\Progra~2\Java\jre7
%JRE_HOME%\bin\java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.34.0.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=.\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.39.0.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver_win32_2.10.exe`

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
```

Comment: none of the other ones work. For security reasons a javascript

Answer (score 4):

Selenium 2.31.0

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Resize the window to the screen width/height
driver.set_window_size(300, 500)

# Move the window to position x/y
driver.set_window_position(200, 200)
```

Comment: this should be in Python?

Answer (score 2):

for Firefox:
sel.key_press_native(122)
(122 in the key code for F11)

Comment: that's an interesting bit of trivia.  I didn't know you could do that.  While it's probably not what he was looking for, it would be good for scripted presentations.

Answer (score 2):

Well I think the best way is to use ***selenium.windowMaximize()*** selenium function instead of manipulating the windows size.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers provided work when passing the **-singlewindow** parameter to the Selenium RC server. However, if you pass a firefox profile to the Selenium RC server ([as detailed somewhat here](http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/)), you can make an empty profile folder and put this file in the folder:

[**localstore.rdf***(case sensitive filename!)*](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Localstore.rdf):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF:RDF xmlns:NC="http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#"
         xmlns:RDF="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#main-window"
                   sizemode="normal"
                   height="9999"
                   width="9999"
                   screenX="0"
                   screenY="0" />
                   lastSelected="paneTabs" />
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul">
    <NC:persist RDF:resource="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#main-window"/>
    <NC:persist RDF:resource="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#PersonalToolbar"/>
    <NC:persist RDF:resource="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#nav-bar"/>
    <NC:persist RDF:resource="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#status-bar"/>
    <NC:persist RDF:resource="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#toggle_taskbar"/>
    <NC:persist RDF:resource="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#navigator-toolbox"/>
    <NC:persist RDF:resource="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#toolbar-menubar"/>
    <NC:persist RDF:resource="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#sidebar-box"/>
    <NC:persist RDF:resource="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#sidebar-title"/>
  </RDF:Description>
</RDF:RDF>
```

Replace width and height with your preferred width and height. 9999x9999 will pretty much maximize any monitor.

The simplest example possible of running your Selenium RC server this way assuming we have the previously mentioned **localstore.rdf** in our home directory, and we are currently in the directory of the Selenium RC server:

```
rm -rf ~/ffProfile
mkdir ~/ffProfile
cp localstore.rdf ~/ffProfile
java -jar selenium-server-*.jar -singlewindow -firefoxProfileTemplate "~/ffProfile"
```

This also has the added benefit of not "polluting" your tests.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on David Hunt's suggestion for more specific window resizing and moving note the following.

To work in most environments move before resizing. That is:

> selenium.getEval("window.moveTo(X, Y); window.resizeTo(X, Y); ")

To cover 2/3's of the screen, which is handy for seeing part of the selenium driving window underneath, and to do this regardless of your target screen resolution:

> selenium.getEval("window.moveTo(screen.availWidth / 3,0); window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth * (2/3), screen.availHeight); ");

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, the call would be

> web_driver.manage.window.maximize