# Resize Window using Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I am trying to resize the width/height of my browser window using Selenium IDE. I am aware that there is the function:

```
window.resizeTo(480, 725)
```

but getting this executed within Selenium IDE is causing me some grief. Would I need to write a custom function?

Answer (score 2):

```
WebDriver driver = ((WebDriverBackedSelenium) selenium).getWrappedDriver();
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522252/how-to-resize-maximize-firefox-window-during-launching-selenium-remote-control)

Comment: thanks but im using Selenium IDE, how would i implement this within that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to resize window in selenium IDE is set this command into your script(s):

```
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>javascript{window.opener.resizeTo(1920,1080);}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

i.e.

```
Command: runScript
Target: javascript{window.opener.resizeTo(1920,1080);}
Value: <empty>
```

About 'window.opener' property: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I found to resize a window in Selenium IDE is to open the page in a new window before attempting to resize it.

```
<td>openWindow</td>
<td>http://'website or page to be opened'</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>selectWindow</td>
<td>title='title of website/page'</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>getEval</td>
<td>window.resizeTo(1080,800);</td>
<td></td>
```

When not opening the page in a new window, Selenium would see/execute the resize command but it would ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Above works but it resizes the selenium IDE window. If you want to resize the actual firefox window, try this javascript command.

`javascript{window.opener.resizeTo(x,y)}`